# Date Picker on a button click in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

i know this question is asked many times , but i'm facing an issue that my date picker  is not opening when i click the button, and after selection i want to show its value in a label. My code is,

```
datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
datepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 216 - 44, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
[toolBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(ShowSelectedDate)];
UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneBtn,space,nil]];

// _label1.text:datepicker.date;

-(void)ShowSelectedDate {
    NSDateFormatter *fromatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [fromatter setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy"];
    _label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[fromatter stringFromDate:datepicker.date]];
    [_label1 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: you can use datepicker of Actionsheetpicker lib

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would create an `IBAction` for your button to call to show the `UIDatePicker`. Then implement the `UIDatePicker` delegate methods and set the text of your label.

**Objective C**

Define Globally

```
UIToolbar* toolbar;
UIDatePicker* picker;
```

In your header file:

```
-(IBAction)showDatePicker:(id)sender;
```

In your implementation file

```
- (IBAction)showDatePicker:(id)sender {
    picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    picker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [picker setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:@"textColor"];
    
    picker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    picker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    
    [picker addTarget:self action:@selector(dueDateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    picker.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 300, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 300);
    [self.view addSubview:picker];
    
    toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 300, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 50)];
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    toolbar.items = @[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil], [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(onDoneButtonClick)]];
    [toolbar sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
}

-(void) dueDateChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
    
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    
    NSLog(@"Picked the date %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]]);
    YOUR_LABEL.TEXT = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]];
}

-(void)onDoneButtonClick {
    [toolbar removeFromSuperview];
    [picker removeFromSuperview];
}
```

**Swift 4.2**

Define Globally

```
var toolBar = UIToolbar()
var datePicker  = UIDatePicker()
```

Write code in Your Button Action.

```
@IBAction func showDatePicker(_ sender: UIButton) {
    datePicker = UIDatePicker.init()
    datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            
    datePicker.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
            
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dateChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 300, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 300)
    self.view.addSubview(datePicker)
            
    toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 300, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 50))
    toolBar.barStyle = .blackTranslucent
    toolBar.items = [UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil), UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.onDoneButtonClick))]
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    self.view.addSubview(toolBar)
}

@objc func dateChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker?) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
        
    if let date = sender?.date {
        print("Picked the date \(dateFormatter.string(from: date))")
    }
}

@objc func onDoneButtonClick() {
    toolBar.removeFromSuperview()
    datePicker.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: It is showing only a black blank screen when i click the button . @Kuldeep

Comment: @Oneeb, You just need to change TextColor like this  [picker setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:@"textColor"];

Comment: Yup it is showing now but i want done button on it after selection the date picker is not dismissing , the done button should dismiss the date picker. @Kuldeep

Comment: U have changed the background color it is same as before. I want a button above the date picker as a bar button when i click it it should dismiss the date picker.@Kuldeep

Comment: @Oneeb please review code, I have added UIToolBar over DatePicker with Done Button

Comment: @Oneeb please upVote this answer so other can use this answer in feature.

Comment: @Kuldeep, upvoted. One suggestion: edit the answer and put swift code on top, people are coming here for swift not Objective C anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Although the question is for Objective-C, My answer for **Swift 5.0**

```
private lazy var datePicker : UIDatePicker = {
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        datePicker.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            datePicker.backgroundColor = .label
        } else {
            datePicker.backgroundColor = .white
        }
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dateChanged), for: .valueChanged)
        return datePicker
    }()
    
    private lazy var toolBar : UIToolbar = {
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        toolBar.barStyle = .default
        toolBar.items = [UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil), UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.onDoneClicked))]
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        return toolBar
    }()
    
@objc private func onDoneClicked(picker : UIDatePicker) {
        
    }
    
    @objc private func dateChanged(picker : UIDatePicker) {
        
    }

private func addDatePicker() {
        self.view.addSubview(self.datePicker)
        self.view.addSubview(self.toolBar)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.datePicker.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
            self.datePicker.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor),
            self.datePicker.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor),
            self.datePicker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.toolBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.datePicker.topAnchor),
            self.toolBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor),
            self.toolBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor),
            self.toolBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        ])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
 -(IBAction)showDatePicker:(id)sender
    {

    UIDatePicker* picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
                        picker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
                        picker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

 [picker addTarget:self action:@selector(dueDateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
                        CGSize pickerSize = [picker sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
                        picker.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 250, pickerSize.width, 460);
                        picker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                        [self.view addSubview:picker];
                        [picker release];


    }

-(void) dueDateChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

    //self.myLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[dueDatePickerView date]];
    NSLog(@"Picked the date %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]]);
}
```

Comment: It is showing only a black blank screen when i click the button .@Sanjay Kumaar

Comment: Did you add this in your header file `-(IBAction)showDatePicker:(id)sender;`-@Oneeb

Comment: yes  i have write it under a button action. @Sanjay Kumaar

Comment: change different color from black background.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added your `datePicker` to your view anywhere in the code.
 Try like this

```
datepicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 216, self.view.frame.size.width, 216)];
datepicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;

[self.view addSubview:picker]; // adding picker to your view
```

Moreover you haven't added `toolbar` to your view also. So, do it like this

```
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: It is showing the date picker but its transparent color and it is showing at the top of the screen , i want to show it at bottom of screen and after selecting a date i have to show it in a label. @Aditiya Srivastava

Comment: I have edited my answer with datePicker frame. You can use it will solve your picker showing top of the screen problem. @Oneeb